# Triangulation vs. Trilateration

Tags: geometry, terminology, definition, triangulation

Are **triangulation** and **trilateration** different words for the exact same procedure, or is there a small technical difference between the two?

If there is a small difference, which is the correct term for locating Point $P$ when the distances between $P$ and points $A$, $B$, and $C$ are known?

Finally, what is the term for the 3-dimensional equivalent with 4 spheres that GPS uses to also calculate a location's altitude?

An answer with visual examples is appreciated.

Comment: Mathematical meaning of the word "triangulation" is utterly different from what you have in mind.

Comment: ^Are you able to define it and explain how it is different?

Comment: How much topology do you know? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulation_(topology)

Comment: From Wikipedia's ["Triangulation" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulation): *"[T]he process of determining the location of a point by forming triangles to the point from known points."* From its ["Trilateration" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilateration): *"[T]he use of distances [...] for determining the unknown position coordinates of a point of interest"*, noting later, *"Trilateration [...] should not be confused with triangulation, which uses angles for positioning"*. They are different notions.

Comment: @Blue: This Wikipedia article was written by somebody with limited mathematical background and does not contain a single math reference. I do not think the terminology "triangulation" (as described in the link) is used anywhere in math.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: Perhaps "triangulation" in that sense might be considered a term-of-art more in [surveying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulation_(surveying)) than mathematics-proper, but I believe I was first introduced to that sense of the term in my high school math classes. ... *shrug* ... Of course, I'm also aware of "triangulation" in the polygonal-subdivision/topological sense, but I suspect OP is interested in the former. (BTW: I don't take Wikipedia's word for *everything* —anyone can edit it, after all— but I didn't think the definitions I cited seemed controversial.)

Answer (score 4):

While I wouldn't say this is the mathematical definition for it, [this GIS (Geographic Information Systems) post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17344/differences-between-triangulation-and-trilateration) has the difference as: Triangulation is finding a point based off of given angles from other points, while Trilateration is finding a point based off of distance.

Here's an image I made based off of one of the images in that post:
[image: Triangulation vs Trilateration]

So I would feel that trilateration is the better term for your context. If you want to move it up to higher dimensions, I would suggest possibly just using trilateration or 4-Point trilateration.